# FTP blocked. Alternate ways to upload file to server?

Tags: ftp

I'm working on a big website right now and I don't have the option of working on local server right now. From the place I'm working, FTP is blocked. I need some way so that I can conveniently upload my files to my server. My site's got a CPanel, but that's really slow and frustating.

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: WebDav sucks, but this is exactly what its for. will your server allow it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

- **Dropbox**
- **Skype/MSN** file transfer (if you are on a VPS or Dedicated and have rights to install software)
- **Teamviewer / GoToMy PC** file transfer (if you are on a VPS or Dedicated and have rights to install software)
- **Email** (may be very slow but will work)
- **Frontpage** extensions.
  You could write a small program which allows you to upload files to your server. Your interface could easily contain a text box which would allow you to specify where on the machine it is to be saved?
- **RDP** to a location where it is not blocked. Use one of the methods above to get it to another machine which can then FTP across.